# The expectation of event occurrence (two-state model in CTMC)

Tags: markov-chains, poisson-process, renewal-processes

Below problem is excerpted from *Stochastic Processes (2e, Ross)*. The solution for 5.12(b) can be found [here](http://www.charmpeach.com/category/stochastic-processes/page/2/).

5.12 Suppose that the “state” of the system can be modeled as a two-state continuous-time Markov chain with transition rates $\nu_0=\lambda$, $\nu_1=\mu$
. When the state of the system is $i$, “events” occur in accordance with a Poisson process with rate
$\alpha_i$, $i=0, 1$. Let $N(t)$ denote the number of events in $(0, t)$.

(b) If the initial state is state $0$, find $E\big(N(t)\big)$.

I am not sure about why $E(N(t))=\alpha_0 E(T_0(t))+\alpha_1 E(T_1(t))$, where $T_i(t)$ stands for the time spent in state $i$ before time $t$. It is quite obvious for Poisson process. But I fail to understand it in this case. (I know little about renewal theory, so is it possible to circumvent it?) Also, I think it is a Doubly stochastic Poisson Process (Cox process) instead of the typical conditional Poisson process. Is it true?

Comment: What's $T_0$ and $T_1$?

Comment: Updated the description. $T_i(t)$ stands for the time spent in state $i$ before time $t$.  @lan

Comment: An inelegant way to do it is to recursively condition on the time of the next jump; then I think you have $E[N(t) \mid X_0=0]=\int_0^t (E[N(t-s) \mid X_0=1]+\alpha_0 s) \lambda e^{-\lambda s} ds + \alpha_0 t (1-e^{-\lambda t})$. You can continue this procedure in alternating fashion until the residual term is as small as you like.

Comment: The idea for a more elegant solution is sort of evident; the distribution of the number of events that occur while you're in $0$ or $1$ depends only on how long you spend there in total, since the Poisson clock for the events is memoryless and independent of the state dynamics. But I don't see a nice way to formalize that observation.

Comment: Ah, maybe this can be seen as two segregated alternated jump processes. The duration of each occurrence follows an exponential distribution. Then $\alpha_i E(T_i(t))$ accounts for the number of jumps.@lan

Answer (score 1):

Sketch of the solution:
Let $M(t) = E(N_t|X_0=0)$. Conditioning on the state at $t$, we have $M^{'}(t)=\alpha_0P_{00}(t)+\alpha_1 P_{01}(t).$

The transition probability $P_{0i}$ can be solved via the Kolmogorov forward equation.